# Error: The getter 'path' isn't defined for the type 'File'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

Please help me to resolve below error

```
import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;

uploadFile(
    File _selectedDocument,
    List<int> _selectedFile,
    BuildContext context,
    String fileNotes,
    String fileName,
    String fileTitle) async {
  print("Upload start...");

  var token = await readLocalStorageData("token");
  var fileContentType = mime(_selectedDocument.path)!.split('/'); <====== Error
  var uri = Uri.parse('${Constants.apiEndPoint}/consumerUploadFile');
  var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);
  request.fields['Token'] = token;

  request.files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('File', _selectedFile,
      contentType: MediaType(fileContentType[0], fileContentType[1]),
      filename: path.basename(_selectedDocument.path))); <===== Error

  var streamedResponse = await request.send();
  var response = await http.Response.fromStream(streamedResponse);
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var result = json.decode(response.body.toString());
    if (result['ResponseCode'] == "0") {
      if (result['Data'] != null) {
        //print(result['Data']['banner']);
        await saveDocumentURL(
            result['Data']['banner'], fileName, fileTitle, fileNotes, context);
        saveData("completed", "upload_status");
      }
    } else if (result['ResponseCode'] != "0") {
      await checkErrorResponseCode(context, result['ResponseCode']);
    }
  }
}
```

Error Message : The getter 'path' isn't defined for the type 'File'.
Try importing the library that defines 'path', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'path'.

I already imported "import 'package:path/path.dart' as path;" but this error is still there. How to solve this problem. Please help.

Comment: what is the error

Comment: The getter 'path' isn't defined for the type 'File'.
Try importing the library that defines 'path', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'path'

Comment: *Which* `File` class are you using?  The one from `dart:io`? from `dart:html`?  from `package:file`? from somewhere else?

Comment: I using class from *dart:html*

Comment: [`File` from `dart:html`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-html/File-class.html) does not have a `path` member.  Perhaps you mean its [`relativePath`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-html/File/relativePath.html) member, or maybe you meant to use a different `File` class.

Answer (score 0):

i think only dart:io package has a method .'path', dart:html dosn't have method like .'path' instead it has the method like .'relativePath'

```
import 'dart:io' 
File _selectedDocument;  
var path= _selectedDocument.path;
```

you can try like this

```
import 'dart:html' 
File _selectedDocument;  
var filename=_selectedDocument.name;
var path= _selectedDocument.relativePath;
```